# Process crash after Informix error

Tags: c++, informix, coredump

I have a C++ process which is crashing now and then (mostly when performance testing is done).
When I checked the core logs, I could see lot of Informix errors, before the crash.

I see a series of Informix errors with error code 406, which is related to `Out of Memory` exception, before the process core dumps.
I also see error code 244 (could not do a physical-order read to fetch next row).

Can someone share your thoughts on how these scenarios can result in the process core dumping?

**More Details**

Process : Multithreaded C++ process
Environment: Solaris
Database: Informix with ESQL interface

ESQL DB function (Insert/Update/Select) is throwing which is caught by the process. The message in the catch block is the last message appearing in the process logs. After that there is no clue about the process.

The normal message(`Caught signal. dumped core`) which appears when a process coredumps is also missing.

Comment: Is it your C++ program that's core dumping or the Informix server?  Are you using a threaded C++ program?  Are you using the threaded libraries?  Which interface are you using (ODBC, ESQL/C, OLEDB, ...)?  Which platform is the program running on?  The database server?  Which versions are you using?  How does your application deal with error reports?  What does the online log file have to say?  Etc.  There are a myriad issues that could be the trouble.  The server shouldn't be crashing, though.  It can do all sorts of things, but crashing is not one of them.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - It's a multithreaded C++ process. It uses ESQL interface. Process is running on Solaris. The process is crashing without any clue. The last logs I see in the process logs is a series of Informix errors. Even the log which says, process has core dumped, is missing. The pstack does not give the correct information too.

Comment: Are you linking with the thread-safe(r) ESQL/C libraries?  This is Solaris; is that 8, 9, 10, or 11?  Which version of ESQL/C?  Are you sharing connections between threads properly?  Are you aware of SET CONNECTION 'conn_name' DORMANT?  Do you establish connections before or after the threads are established?  Does each thread that communicates with the DB get its own connection?  (My impression from your comments is that it is your C++ program that crashes, not the Informix data server; is that correct?)

Comment: Yes, it is the process that crashes. What I said is the informix errors(406-Out of memory exception) keeps on coming. I feel memory gets exhausted and process crashes due to out of memory. Can that happen?

Comment: Which version of Informix server?.. What does the Informix ol logfile say?.. What are the onconfig parameters?

Comment: Are you by any chance using Boost Asio libraries?.. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html

Answer (score 1):

When you said `during performance testing` there you have a huge clue !!!!!

Typically for performance test cases the compiler optimizations are cranked up resulting in short circuiting some of the not so well written code resulting in crashes.

To give you a typical case : variables are not declared volatile when they are supposed to be read across threads.

Comment: Can you give an example, how `volatile` can affect in threaded programs? Mine is a multithreaded process.

Comment: http://www.eetimes.com/discussion/beginner-s-corner/4023801/Introduction-to-the-Volatile-Keyword good article.